# Code that runs before JUnits TestsSuite or specificaly set up a test that will execute first and last. ( only first and last, not all )

Tags: java, junit

I have been searching for something like this, but all what I have found was Fixed test order or completely random.

I have this kind of a test structure:

```
// imports

@RunWith(Suite.class)

@Suite.SuiteClasses({
        // Tests
})

public class TestRunSuite {
}
```

and what do I want to do:

```
// imports

@RunWith(Suite.class)

@Suite.SuiteClasses({
        testToExecuteFirst.class,
        // Tests in random order
        testToExecuteLast.class
})

public class TestRunSuite {
}
```

**or**

Is there a way how to make TestSuite execute in the middle of 2 functions ?
What do I mean:

```
authentificationSetUp();
// somehow calling TestRunSuite
authentificationSetUpBack();
```

The reason why do I want to do this, is that I need to change the timeout of authentification on one website, but the thing is, that I need to logged in as an admin and tests are for other roles. So instead of going through all of those tests and putting to each @BeforeClass and @AfterClass these 2 tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply add a @BeforeClass method and an @AfterClass method inside your TestRunSuite class.

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
        // Tests
})

public class TestRunSuite {

    @BeforeClass
    public void authentificationSetUp() {
        //Your code
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void authentificationSetUpBack() {
        //Your code
    }

}
```